# My code generates a lot of Ajax requests. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have this code but it generates a lot of Ajax requests:

```
$scope.form = function (type, id) {
  params = {'id': id};

  if (type == 'isExperience') {
    var route = "seeqle_user_profile_experience_form";
  }

  $http.get(Routing.generate(route, params,true)).success(function (template) {
    $scope.openModal(template);
  });
}
```

In the network tab of my Chrome dev tools, I see this result:

[image]

Thank you, Stack Overflow

Comment: You'll need to include how and where `$scope.form` is getting called..

Comment: in my html i have this code click="form('isExperience', 13)"

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so the community can be more effective at helping you.